# What happens to a published app in the App Store if you cancel you Indie Seat with Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I published an app to the App Store using Titanium Studio in 2013. I have recently found a bug in the code that I want to fix and publish.

I logged into Appcelerator's website to download the latest studio since it's been three years, only to find out that it's a paid platform now.

I just want to make a quick bug fix and publish. I don't need any of the services that come with the platform.

I realize there is a free SDK that you can compile yourself, etc, etc.

I don't mind paying for a $36 for one month only if it enables me to just publish a new version of my app.

My question is, if I publish the app after paying the $36 and then cancel my subscription, will the cancellation affect my app? Does the IDE inject some sort of "call home" time bomb?

I tried asking the support at appcelerator but they answered like a politician and dodged it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A published/compiled app has no direct connection with appcelerator. So if you cancel the subscription nothing happens.

However, if you use paid services... things might go wrong.

Statistics for example is a paid service. If you cancel subscription I assume the app keeps working but will make calls to their backend that most likely will fail (not sure about this). App should keep working.

If you use any cloud service (push notifications, arrow storage etc) your app will stop working of course.

If you don't use any of the services, you can just cancel and be done with it.

That said, if you just want to make 1 change to an app you could just dive in and compile without the Appcelerator Platform and just use the Open Source code.